# Running a program that needs a package's old version

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I want to run a program with a demo of oauth which gives this error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `materialize': Could not find crack-0.1.8 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in `map!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:82:in `materialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:107:in `specs'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:152:in `specs_for'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/definition.rb:141:in `requested_specs'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23:in `requested_specs'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
from example.rb:2
```

I found running it needs crack-0.1.8. When I ran `gem list`, I found the crack version in my computer is 0.3.1, so how can I solve this problem? (The new version is not compatible with the old version? I am confused.)

Answer (score 0):

Just specify version of this gem in  `Gemfile`

```
gem crack, '0.1.8'
```

Comment: it Could not find crack-0.1.8 in any of the sources,if i specify '0.1.8' the result is the same.if i specify '0.3.1' ,it shows another problem:

Comment: Have you specified your sources in your gemfile? source :rubygems if nothing else...

Answer (score 0):

Run `bundle install`, which will install the correct versions of all the Gems needed, as specified in the Gemfile. It should run okay after that.

Answer (score 0):

`Crack 0.1.8` is available at rubygems.org:

- [Crack at rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org/gems/crack)
- [Crack 0.1.8 at rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org/gems/crack/versions/0.1.8)

With

```
gem install crack -v 0.1.8
```

it should be possible to install the version you need.